# compare month and year in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I want to compare month and year columns in my table with month and year parameters provided by user I used to put this expression

```
 select  ca_expense_mst.trans_id, trans_no
 from ca_expense_mst , CA_EXPENSE_FINANCE_DTL fndDtl     
 where  ca_expense_mst.TRANS_ID=fndDtl.TRANS_ID    
 and TO_DATE(''|| fndDtl.year ||'/'|| fndDtl.month || '/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')  between  TO_DATE(''|| :fromYear ||'/'|| :fromMonth || '/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')  and TO_DATE(''|| :toYear ||'/'|| :toMonth || '/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')     
 and  fndDtl.account_id= nvl(to_number(:account_no),fndDtl.account_id)
```

it works fine but if I add the aggregate function `count()` I get this exception:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

I need a method so that I can compare moth and year column with month and year parameters

this is the SQL that throws the exception:

```
select  count(ca_expense_mst.trans_id)  as all_trans
from ca_expense_mst , CA_EXPENSE_FINANCE_DTL fndDtl     
where  ca_expense_mst.TRANS_ID=fndDtl.TRANS_ID    
and TO_DATE(''|| fndDtl.year ||'/'|| fndDtl.month || '/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')  between  TO_DATE(''|| 
:fromYear ||'/'|| :fromMonth || '/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')  and TO_DATE(''|| :toYear ||'/'|| :toMonth || '/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') 
and  fndDtl.account_id= nvl(to_number(:account_no),fndDtl.account_id)
```

here is the script of my table

```
CREATE TABLE SAS_ADF.CA_EXPENSE_FINANCE_DTL
(
  EXP_FIN_ID          NUMBER,
  ACCOUNT_ID          NUMBER,
  TRANS_ID            NUMBER,
  AMOUNT_BY_CD        NUMBER,
  DEBIT_CREDIT        VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  CHEQUE_STATUS       VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  REFERENCE_NO        VARCHAR2(500 BYTE),
  REFERENCE_DATE      DATE,
  ENT_BY              VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  ENT_DATE            DATE,
  MODIFY_BY           VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  MODIFY_DATE         DATE,
  REFUND_TYPE_ID      NUMBER,
  STUDENT_ID          NUMBER,
  STD_FIN_APP_FLAG    VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  STD_AUDIT_APP_FLAG  VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  ACTION_DATE         DATE,
  MONTH               NUMBER,
  YEAR                NUMBER,
  CANCEL_FLAG         VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  EXP_FIN_ID_M        NUMBER,
  USER_TRANS_ID       VARCHAR2(500 BYTE),
  OLD_STUDENT_ID      NUMBER,
  CD                  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  CURRENCY_RATE       NUMBER,
  AMOUNT_BY_CD_L      NUMBER,
  CURR_ISO            VARCHAR2(4 BYTE),
  STDUENT_ID_W        NUMBER,
  AMOUNT_BY_CD_C      NUMBER,
  DEBIT_CREDIT_C      VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
)
```

and here is screen shot of some data

[image]

Comment: If this used to work but stopped working, I would suspect a data issue. Could there be a row with an invalid month or year value?

Comment: no I test it in toad using the same data and same parameter value, i think it is bug, but i need to do the comparison in some other method.
the problem is not unique to my SQL only, try it yourself using your own tables and you willget the same error, this is why Im saying it's bug. I just want to filter out the irrelevant data

Comment: In any case, you don't need to recompute the TO_STRING conversions for FromYear, fromMonth, toYear and toMonth for every comparison. I would declare 4 variables and compute these at the top, then in the query compare against the variables.

Comment: BTW, isn't the logic flawed here? `BETWEEN` is inclusive and your _upper_ bound is the _first_ day of the end month ?

Comment: Doug Leavy: please expain with an example I could not get your solution.

Sylvain: the logic is tested several times and it works fine in other Queries where I don't need Count().
only this time when I put the count I got the error

Comment: _"the problem is not unique to my SQL only, try it yourself using your own tables and you willget the same error, this is why Im saying it's bug"_ is you think this is a bug with Oracle, could you provide a [small but working example (incl. relevant data)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) depicting that issue in order to investigate that in depth? Maybe using http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: I see that you are using Oracle - which I am not specifically familiar with.

Comment: Just to clarify it is not data issue - `select * from CA_EXPENSE_FINANCE_DTL where not (year between -4713 and 9999) or year = 0` - any rows here?

Comment: @beherenow Maybe `select * from CA_EXPENSE_FINANCE_DTL where year is null` too ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux yeah, but null year yields another error

Comment: another possible issue is, if year is < 0 (not < -4713) then you need to specify "S" in date format mask. like this: `select TO_DATE( -2001 ||'/'|| 1 || '/01', 'syyyy/mm/dd')` from dual (compare it with yyyy/mm/dd)

Comment: - be here now: your SQL brought no records.

- Sylvian: your SQL brought 2 records

- just a reminder, if i remove count() in my sql and put normal columns it works fine, so i don't think it is data issue

Comment: @beherenow As a matter of fact it will produce the same error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/39003

Comment: @SylvainLeroux right. I tested null with `syyyy` mask in to date - with this one it throws ORA-01858, however with `yyyy` it is ORA-01841. so, a data issue?

Comment: @user1512999 "it works fine" - do you conclude that after fetching ALL records from query without count? because if you fetch just first 10/50/1000 rows chances are one of those 2 rows with null year are not among them, so no to_date is done for them, though on the other hand count has to process them all.

Comment: after removing the null values of year it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a NULL value in the column `fndDtl.year`.

Somehow counter-intuitively, this will raise `ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0` with your format:

> ```
> select TO_DATE(''|| NULL ||'/'|| 12 || '/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') from dual;
> ```
>
> *ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0*

---

As a matter of fact you could track down that behavior up to that simple case:

> ```
> select TO_DATE('/', 'yyyy/') from dual
> ```
>
> *ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0*

whereas, as noticed by *be here now* in a comment above:

> ```
> select TO_DATE('/', 'syyyy/') from dual
> ```
>
> *ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected*

Comment: I removed the null values of year and it worked fine, what make me think in different direction is that when I remove the count it works fine. I don't know why.
anyways now it is workring after removing the null values of year

Comment: @user1512999 most likely you just stopped fetching rows before encountering to_date(null). with count this is impossible - it processes all rows before you can fetch anything to client.

Comment: I got it thank you, as I know when executing sql on toa,it fetches 500 rows per time, for sure year =null was not among them.
thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Exclude null values from Year and Month

```
select CA_EXPENSE_MST.TRANS_ID,
       TRANS_NO
  from CA_EXPENSE_MST
 inner join CA_EXPENSE_FINANCE_DTL FNDDTL on CA_EXPENSE_MST.TRANS_ID = FNDDTL.TRANS_ID
 where CA_EXPENSE_MST.TRANS_ID is not null
   and FNDDTL.YEAR is not null
   and FNDDTL.MONTH is not null
   and FNDDTL.ACCOUNT_ID = NVL(TO_NUMBER(:ACCOUNT_NO), FNDDTL.ACCOUNT_ID)
   and TO_DATE(FNDDTL.YEAR || '/' || FNDDTL.MONTH || '/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') between TO_DATE(:FROMYEAR || '/' || :FROMMONTH || '/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') and
       TO_DATE(:TOYEAR || '/' || :TOMONTH || '/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

Here is the link: [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/66566/3)